# jQuery DataTables - adding rows resets pagination and filtering

Tags: jquery, datatable, datatables, datatables-1.10

I'm using jQuery DataTables in a console app.

The following code adds a row to the DataTable:

```
$('#datatable-table').dataTable().fnAddData([
    '<h1>test</h1>',
    'test',
    'test',
    'test',
    'test',
    'test',
    'test',
    'test',
    'test',
    'test',
    'test'
]);
```

The problem is, when you programmatically add a row, it resets the user's pagination and filtering. So if a user is on page 3, when I update the table, he will go back to page 1. Which doesn't really work for me considering I'm constantly needing to add/remove/update rows.

Any suggestions?

Comment: I guess I'm looking for something similar to this that isn't deprecated: http://www.datatables.net/plug-ins/api/fnStandingRedraw

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Version 1.10 of jQuery DataTables has a [`page()`](https://datatables.net/reference/api/page()) method which allows you to get or set the current page of your table.

For example:

```
    var table = $('#myTable').DataTable();

    $('#btn').click(function() {
       table.row.add( [
           'new 1',
           'new 2'
        ]);

        var currentPage = table.page();  
        table.page(currentPage).draw(false);        
    });
```

After adding a new row, the code gets the current page, and then sets the table to that page when it is re-drawn.

jsfiddle demo [here](http://jsfiddle.net/wo4zkf5c/1/). Hope it helps.

Comment: There is no need to set a page, calling `draw(false)` is enough, see [this jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/wo4zkf5c/2/).

Comment: Yes true but setting the page object gives you more options, such as moving to the next / previous page for example. I was just trying to demonstrate this.